# How to get form elements labels enclosed in <label> tag

Tags: php, zend-framework, label, zend-form

I am creating checkbox elements in Zend Form like this:

```
$element = $this->CreateElement('checkbox', 'CheckIt');
$element->setLabel('Check It');
$elements[] = $element;
```

When I get label like this:

```
echo $this->element->getElement("CheckIt")->getLabel();
```

It outputs:

```
Check It
```

But I want following output:

```
<label for='CheckIt'>Check It</label>
```

Is there any option in getLabel() function or is there any other function to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: no, you gotta build your own, it will probably take you less time to write than you did writing this question. Or maybe what you actaully ment is you need custom decorators or viewscripts?

Comment: @max4ever: Yes.. I am asking for that solution that takes less time than writing this question. I am not familiar with decorators. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**renderLabel()**

```
<?php echo $this->form->getElement("CheckIt")->renderLabel(); ?>
```

render that label

Comment: +1 I'll be darned, they overload for specific decorators. In it's default it wraps it in a `dt` element, though.

Comment: @adrian there is a secret to that too! for each of your elements, add this call to get rid of all the unwanted decorators: $element->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper', 'Label', 'Errors')); note that simply calling $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper'); is not sufficient

Answer (score 1):

i'm affraid that while decorators are boring to study and understand, once you understand them, they are usefull

this is one of my classes, you can easily addapt it to meet your needs

```
<?php
class My_Label extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    protected $_format = '<td class="nome_campo"><label for="%s">%s%s</label></td>';

    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();

        $id      = htmlentities($element->getId(), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $label   = htmlentities($element->getLabel(), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        if ($element->isRequired())
            $asterisk = '<span class="required">*</span> ';
        else
            $asterisk = '';

        $markup = sprintf($this->_format, $id, $asterisk, $label);


        //per avere valid xhtml/html
        if (stripos($element->getType(), 'radio') !== false )//Zend_Form_Element_Radio
        {
            $this->_format = '<td class="nome_campo">%s%s</td>';
            $markup = sprintf($this->_format, $asterisk, $label);
        }


        $placement = $this->getPlacement();
        $separator = $this->getSeparator();
        switch ($placement) {
            case self::APPEND:
                return $content . $separator . $markup;
            case self::PREPEND:
            default:
                return $markup . $separator . $content;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual misunderstanding in your question: `getLabel()` is a simple getter method for a property on an object.

```
$element; // is a Zend_Element object
$label = $element->getLabel(); // returns the value of the label property and not a HTML string
```

If you want an HTML output you have to call `render()` on the object but this will render the whole form and not just the label value. You may disable the decorators for the element but then you will have enable them again when you render the form itself.

Plus there is a formal error in your question. It is either

```
$element->getLabel();
// or once you have added the element to the form
$this->getElement('CheckIt')->getLabel();
```